# webpack and django on Heroku: bundling before collectstatic

Tags: python, node.js, django, heroku, webpack

I am building a django+react app on Heroku, using `django-npm` which automatically installs all modules from `package.json` to `node-modules` dir and then copies everything to `staticfiles/` during `python manage.py collectstatic` (which is triggered by Heroku during deploy).

However, for this configuration to work I need to pre-bundle my React app before deployment and put it into my `static` folder along with all the CSS, fonts, etc. to be picked up by `collectstatic` later.

But I don't want to pollute my git diffs with new bundle versions. So, is there a way to make webpack create a bundle during deployment?

I know there is a `release` command on Heroku where I can put my `npm run build`. But the problem is it only fires AFTER `collectstatic`, so my bundle will only be created in `static/` folder after this folder is scanned, and won't get copied to `staticfiles` dir.

Comment: why not re-run collectstatic in the heroku release command after npm build. Something like `release: npm run build && python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
Using `bin/pre_compile` should no longer be necessary as of March 11, 2019. Heroku will now automatically call an app's `build` script (if defined in `package.json`) during Heroku's build process. Source: [Heroku Changelog](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1557).

---

**Original:** You can accomplish this with the (undocumented) `pre_compile` hook exposed by the `heroku/python` buildpack.

Add an executable shell file named `bin/pre_compile` at the top level of your app and it will be [called automatically](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/d7351513c76d7dd49712a11d5cecc7411c9154fe/bin/compile#L189) as part of the build process.

```sh
cd my-django-app
mkdir bin
echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash' >> bin/pre_compile
echo 'npm run build' >> bin/pre_compile
chmod +x bin/pre_compile
```